# Clarification on editing clashes

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I recently had an edit rejected (not complaining) as while [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1527109) was awaiting approval, a >2k user [made the same edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14892790/revisions) I had made (which at this stage had two approvals)

This has confused me slightly as I thought that when an edit was in review, the post would be locked to further edits to prevent multiple edits being submitted and clashing.  Is this not the case or is it only this way for <2k users?

Comment: Afaik, posts are never locked when a user started editing. It will be locked from editing when a suggested edit is awaiting review.

Comment: @Bart I mean when the edit has been submitted for review and is in the suggested edits review queue. Would it not be locked to edits then? :S

Comment: Yes, once the edit has been suggested. But a clash can still happen if two users started editing before one submitted the suggestion. (Afaik).

Comment: That could be the reason then. There is only 3 minutes between the two edits actually being submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bart's answer within the question comments was correct.

Myself and another user were both editing the same answer at the same time. The post was not locked to edits as we both opened the edit feature before the other user had locked in their edit by submitting it.

As the other user had more than 2000 rep, his edit was immediately approved even though mine was in the suggested edits review queue with two approvals at the time when he submitted his. This in effect made the community user reject my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The edit was rejected by the community user. This normally means, a reviewer has chosen to improve on the edit and unchecked the "was this edit helpful" box.

Normally this is used to improve on a bad edit. But if the improver did not change a thing it is a bit suspicious.

Comment: Not entirely sure the improve route is the case. I think in some cases Community will also reject as the result of a clash.

Comment: The time stamps of the rejection and the edit are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, which would be as expected even in the case of a clash I think.

Comment: Point, but still both scenarios are possible.

Comment: Bart is correct in this case I believe. Fab reviewed the same post from a different queue - http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1527098

Comment: Nice find sherlock ;-).

Comment: When reviewer review by improving button, his name also come in the review page [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1390746)